# How can I have one Party in BizTalk use two different GS02 segments for the same EDI Message type?

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2009, hipaa

I have a connection to an EDI clearinghouse to whom I send X12 270 documents using BizTalk 2009.  The "Information Source" for these 270s can be either of two depending on a variety of factors.  For one Information Source, the clearinghouse requires one value in my GS02, and for the other, they require a different GS02 value.

I see that I can set up multiple entries in my Party Management for the 270, but I do not know how to make the send port know which entry to use.

Has anyone else run into this?

If so, is there a way to do this dynamically, or do I need some other work-around?

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but replying to the question for the sake of others looking for the answer by searching first.

Look into the property EdiOverride.GS02 as part of Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.BaseArtifacts

You only need one party and then filter on the GS02 property at the send port.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/biztalkediandas2/thread/09869a35-f90e-4ca7-9ddd-34c03127710d